# How can i select the highest bid for every card?

Tags: database, postgresql

What we are trying to achieve is to retrieve the highest bid for every card from an auction. Users do not know who has bid how much thus allowing them to bid less or the same amount as other users. The issue we have right now is that we cannot find the right use of `GROUP BY`. For now we have the following queries:

```sql
-- This one does not order the records correctly
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON ("auctionCardId") "auctionCardId", 
    auction_card_bid."userId",
    auction_card_bid.id AS bid_id,
    MAX(auction_card_bid.time),
    MAX(auction_card_bid."bid")
FROM
    auction_card_bid auction_card_bid
    INNER JOIN auction_card ac ON ac.id = auction_card_bid."auctionCardId"
GROUP BY
    auction_card_bid.id,
    auction_card_bid."auctionCardId";
```

```sql
-- Orders the records correctly but it essentially returns all the records
SELECT
    "auctionCardId",
    auction_card_bid."userId",
    auction_card_bid.id AS bid_id,
    MAX(auction_card_bid.time),
    MAX(auction_card_bid."bid")
FROM
    auction_card_bid auction_card_bid
    INNER JOIN auction_card ac on ac.id = auction_card_bid."auctionCardId"
GROUP BY
    auction_card_bid.id,
    auction_card_bid."auctionCardId"
ORDER BY
    auction_card_bid.bid DESC,
    auction_card_bid.time ASC;
```

We have the following database structure:

`auction`

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-05 | 2020-05-06 |

`auction_card`

| id | card_id | auction_id | min_bid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 50 |

`auction_card_bid`

| id | card_id | user_id | bid | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 2020-05-05 10:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 2020-05-05 10:05 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2020-05-05 10:08 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 2020-05-05 10:10 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 40 | 2020-05-05 10:15 |

The ideal result would be something among the lines of:

| user_id | auction_card_id | bid_id | bid | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 2020-05-05 10:05 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 40 | 2020-05-05 10:15 |

Comment: Your first query has a comment reading "This one does not order the records correctly" - but the query lacks an `ORDER BY` clause, so...?

Comment: When added we receive the following error: `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` for which we struggle to find anything relevant on how to solve it

Comment: Are you not familiar with the semantics of `SELECT DISTINCT ON`? (and how it's nothing like `SELECT DISTINCT`...?)

Comment: When providing sample data, please specify correct data, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/pxznygHQ  (`ERROR:  relation "auction_card_bid" does not exist`), and that's not the only inconsistency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, we finally found out how to achieve what we wanted.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("auctionCardId") "auctionCardId" AS  auction_card_id,
                                     auction_card_bid.id bid_id,
                                     value,
                                     time,
                                     "userId",
                                     auction_card."auctionId"
FROM auction_card_bid auction_card_bid
         JOIN auction_card auction_card ON auction_card_bid."auctionCardId" = auction_card.id
WHERE auction_card."auctionId" = 2
ORDER BY "auctionCardId", value DESC, time ASC;
```